# How to sum up a sequence of value in 3 records span?

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry for my broken English, I know the title is weird. But I want to do is like below.
Let' s say I have a `Series`

```
pd.Series([1,3,2,1,4,3])

0    1
1    3
2    2
3    1
4    4
5    3
dtype: int64
```

I want to add each record with the former 2 records and get the Series below.
For instance, for 5th record, the new value 8 = 1 + 4 + 3.

```
0    1
1    4
2    6
3    6
4    7
5    8
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I mean, if you have a gold badge you could just hammer the question.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ If I had known the term "rolling window", I would not ask this question.

Comment: Sorry, the comment was meant for someone else who deleted.